# Triple booting Chromium Os, Ubuntu 14.10, Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I have a lenovo L410, with windows 7 professional pre-installed. On this, I have dual booted Ubuntu 14.10. Now, I want to triple boot with chromium os, but as I have a lot of stuff, I dont want to format or reinstall anything. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible, but if your disk drive has an MS-DOS partition table, there is a limit on the number of partitions. If you have your HDD with GPT partition table it is possible to create more partitions (I don't know how many, but it is a large amount). This is the process I did to triple-boot Ubuntu, Windows 8.1 and Chromium OS with UEFI.

I am supposing that you are able to create the two partitions that Chromium OS needs, and you have them somewhere (an USB drive, a disk image...). You need to create 2 partitions:

- The ROOT partition: I would give this one between 1.5 GiB and 3 GiB. This one only contains the system.
- The STATE partition: This is where your data goes. I gave this one 9 GiB, but anything greater than 2 GiB should be fine.

Once you have created the partitions, you can copy them (using dd). Then you can fit the filesystem to the block device where they are. You can use the "Check" option in GParted or resize2fs.

The interesting part starts here, where you have to create the GRUB entry for Chromium OS. Under Ubuntu, edit the file /etc/grub.d/40_custom and add the following entry:

```
menuentry "Chromium OS" {
     set root=(hd0,YOUR_ROOT_PARTITION_NUMBER)
     linux /boot/vmlinuz init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro noresume noswap loglevel=7 noinitrd console=tty2 quiet root=HDROOTA i915.modeset=1 cros_legacy cros_debug
}
```

You must replace the "YOUR_ROOT_PARTITION_NUMBER" with the number of partition where your Chromium OS ROOT is. If you are using UEFI, you must also change "cros_legacy" with "cros_efi". Now you can create the grub.cfg file:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now we have to tell Chromium OS where the STATE partition is. By default it uses /dev/sdX1, where X is the disk where the ROOT partition is. To change it, edit the file /sbin/chromeos_startup, and change the number "1" of the line `STATE_DEV=${ROOTDEV_TYPE}1` with the number of the STATE partition.

Reboot and enjoy your Chromium OS!